# Как распарсить Json на Python [dweet.io]

Tags: python, json

Нужно из json снизу достать "hello" и "foo";

```
  {
  "this": "succeeded",
  "by": "dweeting",
  "the": "dweet",
  "with": {
    "thing": "my-thing-name",
    "created": "2014-01-15T17:28:42.556Z",
    "content": {
      "hello": "1",
      "foo": "2"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Уточните, "достать"-это получить значение, или убедиться, что есть такой элемент?

Comment: Достать значение из hello и foo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Прежде всего: приведенная Вами в вопросе исходная строка json отличается от той, которую возвращает URL в Вашем коде (во всяком случае, у меня отличаются).
Далее, судя по print() в Вашем ответе, Вы используете Python 3.
Если ориентироваться на строку в вопросе, то для Python 3:

```
import json
jsonstr = '''{
  "this": "succeeded",
  "by": "dweeting",
  "the": "dweet",
  "with": {
    "thing": "my-thing-name",
    "created": "2014-01-15T17:28:42.556Z",
    "content": {
      "hello": "1",
      "foo": "2"
    }
  }
}'''

json = json.loads(jsonstr)
helloval = json['with']['content']['hello']
fooval = json['with']['content']['foo']
print('hello={}'.format(helloval))
print('foo={}'.format(fooval))
```

Answer (score 2):

**Получилось**

```
import json
import requests
url = 'https://dweet.io/get/latest/dweet/for/my-thing-name'
response = requests.get(url)
resp = response.json()
jstr = resp['with']
jstrl = jstr[0]
content = jstrl['content']
print(content)
print(content['foo'])
print(content['hello'])
```

Comment: Код не соответствует примеру в вопросе (`response['with']['content']['hello']`). Нет вложенного списка только словари.